# How to manage custom CSS?

Tags: java, css, spring

I have a widget backed by Java7, Spring for REST URI and HTML/CSS/JS for view part. I want to let my users inject in a backend website css color to customize the widget so I create a form where values are stored in database.

Now, I want to create a custom CSS file with those values that my users can inject in their HTML page. How can I manage this usecase? It will be great if the solution can use Java7 and/or Spring.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be, that you create the CSS file with an JSP (and an spring controller). Then this is just like a dynamic page that has an url that ends with "css".

Comment: Is it cacheable? It's not in my question but it's important.

Comment: @Franck Yapadesouci Anso: do you mean the http response header caching paramers? - Yes: you can set them in the spring controller that is responsible for handling the request.

Comment: I mean if I have two custom CSS from two different users and there is no modification so just return a cacheable version of the JSP previously generated according to who ask the CSS.

Comment: For this use case the ETag is invented, Spring also support this.